# User variable value as type

Tags: redux, flowtype

I try to type `redux` action creators. I have action types like:

```
// @flow
export const SET_USER_TOKEN = "SET_USER_TOKEN";
export const SET_TOKEN_IN_COOKIES = "SET_TOKEN_IN_COOKIES";
```

Now I want to create a type of action creator:

```
import * as actions from "./actions";

type SetUserTokenAction = {
  type: actions.SET_USER_TOKEN,
  token: string
};
```

The problem is with `type` property, I can not do it like above. Do I have to use literal string?

I know it is possible to do something similar for a [whole object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys):

```
type ActionTypes = $Keys<typeof user>;
```

I would like to do the same for the value of a simple string variable.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I don't think it's uncommon for people to just use string literals when using Flow/TypeScript. Because you have type checking, you won't have to worry about typos in strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [typeof](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/typeof/#toc-typeof-type-syntax) oprator:

```
type SetUserTokenAction = {
  type: typeof actions.SET_USER_TOKEN,
  token: string
};
```

The only caveat is to type the const as well ([otherwise its type resolved](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2639) as `string`):

```
export const SET_USER_TOKEN: 'SET_USER_TOKEN' = 'SET_USER_TOKEN';
```

Comment: Yeah, it would be much more convenient if consts were getting literal type like in typescript